# Querying in mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema in the below format:

```
var ServiceSchema = new Schema({ createdAt:Date,name:String,ExpiryDate:Date});
```

I need to query the database comparing the createdAt and expiryDate and get the results.

Say i need to query the values where `createdDate>ExpiryDate`.

Any idea as how to write the query using mongoose will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code snippet should work.

```
ServiceSchema.find( {$where: 'this.createdDate > this.ExpiryDate'}, 
   function(err, results) { 
     ///
});
```

Comment: Thanks will try and let u know :)